# Git - Merge Files From Other Repository

Tags: git, github, merge, pull

Is it possible (And how to) merge files from a different repo and then track pull requests of them, even if your repo isn't a fork?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *It's because I have a fork of a repo and I'm not happy with the current maintainer. I want to make big sweeping changes that would make it basically a whole new repo I know the original maintainer won't merge. But I still want to be able to merge files from him and track his pulls and merges.*

The simplest thing is to continue to be a fork and just don't send pull requests. Forking comes with no obligation to the original repository nor the original maintainer.

If you want a total break, you can create a new repository on Github, send your repository there, and set the upstream repository as a remote manually.

```
git remote add upstream <upstream-url>
```

Let's say you have a fork of [perl5i](https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i). You'd create a new repository on Github. Follow the normal instructions for uploading your existing repository. Then you'd set:

```
 git remote add upstream https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i.git
```

And now you can fetch updates from upstream.

```
 git fetch upsteram
```

Comment: And also I didn't realize (I hadn't tried) that you can change the repo name and still be a fork.

Answer (score 0):

Generally it's possible to merge files from different repositories. Just add multiple remotes, and select which one you want to pull/push changes from/to.

However, in my opinion, this is not a good way of working. It leads to many conflicts, and makes the history very misleading.

Comment: It's because I have a fork of a repo and I'm not happy with the current maintainer. I want to make big sweeping changes that would make it basically a whole new repo I know the original maintainer won't merge.

Comment: But I still want to be able to merge files from him and track his pulls and merges.

Comment: @xendi Continue to be a fork. Just don't send pull requests.

Comment: I suppose. I wish you could change your fork's repo name and still keep it a fork. Can you?

Comment: if you want merge files form other mirror repository, then just specify another remote by addinng their URL. Please use git remote add

Comment: @xendi Yes, you should be able to rename the repo in your settings.

Comment: @RobertPawlak Just add a bit of info from these comments and it is good to be accepted.

Comment: git remote add your_remote git@repo_address.git and then git push/pull your_remote